# Why: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two pieces of code which seems have same functionality but one of them lead to exception but another one is works like a charm. I want to know can you imagine why this happens?

I have below line in my web application which leads to this exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object 
>   FilterDeliveryAddressFields(WebApplication1.Models.DeliveryAddress)'

```
dynamic deliveryAddresses = (from address in db.DeliveryAddress
                             select filterDeliveryAddressFields(address)).ToList();
```

And here is `filterDeliveryAddressFields`:

```
private dynamic filterDeliveryAddressFields(DeliveryAddress address)
{
    return new { address.address, address.deliverTo, address.deliverToPhoneNumber, address.id };
}
```

And here is Linq-2-Sql generated  Model for `DeliveryAddress` which have foreign key relationship with `Subscriber`:

```
public partial class DeliveryAddress
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int fkSubscriberId { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string deliverTo { get; set; }
    public string deliverToPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Subscriber Subscriber { get; set; }
}
```

But when I change `db.DeliveryAddress` items to list first and then run code again as below everything goes well and no exception occurs again. I want to know what wrong with first code snippet which does not happen in below snippet?

```
List<DeliveryAddress> addresseList = db.DeliveryAddress.ToList(); //magic trick?!
dynamic deliveryAddresses =
    (from address in addresseList
     select filterDeliveryAddressFields(address)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your method couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize every method, the magic behind the `.ToList()` method which you are looking for is, after data is loaded, any further operation (such as `select`) is performed using LINQ to Objects, on the data already in memory.

However the performance is not guaranteed in this approach, as you have to load 
 your data into memory, so imagine you have a lot of data in your db, what will be happened next?

Comment: Your concern about loading everything in memory is correct however currently in this specific case, I had to load everything in memory finally since they are returned as JSON in output of a REST web-service. Besides, as an Iranian I appreciate receiving answers from an Iranian expert in Stackoverflow. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Salah . In LINQ to Entities, it first try to convert your query to command tree and execute against your ORM. Please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities) you can find more details.

In your first approach Linq tries to convert your `filterDeliveryAddressFields(address))` method to command tree. That is why it complains that `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method`.

In your second approach you execute against list or `IEnumerable<T>`, which means you use LINQ to Object. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects).

For your first solution you can try another implementation. Simply try to use aggregate method to filter your result. Then you don't need `filterDeliveryAddressFields(address))` method. You can find example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/method-based-query-syntax-examples-aggregate-operators#example-1)

Something like this, (Sorry I didn't try this my self. This is only for you to get an idea.)

```
from address in db.DeliveryAddress
select new { address.address, address.deliverTo, address.deliverToPhoneNumber, address.id };
```